# Metaplex Candy Machine Mint - Error Code: NotFullyLoaded. Error Number: 6020. Error Message: Not all config lines were added to the candy machine

Tags: metaplex, nft, mint, candy-machine-v3

I got an error when minting on candy machine on metaplex js sdk.

here is my setup:

```
    const u1 = Keypair.generate()

    // create collection
    const { nft: collection } = await metaplex
        .nfts()
        .create({
            isCollection: true,
            name: 'MYSOL BADGE COLLECTION',
            symbol: 'MYSBADGE',
            uri: `example.com`,
            sellerFeeBasisPoints: 333, // 3.33%
            mintAuthority: u1,
            updateAuthority: u1,
            tokenOwner: u1.publicKey,
            creators: [
                {
                    share: 100,
                    authority: u1,
                    address: u1.publicKey,
                },
            ],
        })

    // create candy machine
    const { candyMachine } = await metaplex.candyMachines().create({
        withoutCandyGuard: true,
        itemsAvailable: toBigNumber(5),
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 333, // 3.33%
        authority: u1,
        symbol: 'MYSBADGECM',
        itemSettings: {
            type: 'configLines',
            isSequential: true,
            nameLength: 0,
            uriLength: 43,
            prefixName: "My NFT Project #$ID+1$",
            prefixUri: "https://arweave.net/",
        },
        collection: {
            address: collection.address,
            updateAuthority: u1,
        },
        guards: {
            startDate: {
                date: toDateTime(new Date('2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z')),
            },
        }
    });

    // insert items
    const { response } = await metaplex.candyMachines().insertItems({
        candyMachine,
        items: [
            {  name: '', uri: `https://arweave.net/0` }
        ]
    })

    const { nft } = await metaplex.candyMachines().mint({
        candyMachine,
        collectionUpdateAuthority: u1.publicKey,
    })
```

and the above program produces an error like this:

```
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeMint',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2967 of 1000000 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Create',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1622 of 991670 compute units',
    'Program return: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program log: Initialize the associated token account',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeImmutableOwner',
    'Program log: Please upgrade to SPL Token 2022 for immutable owner support',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1405 of 985180 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4241 of 981300 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 20257 of 997033 compute units',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: MintTo',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4536 of 976776 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Mint',
    'Program log: AnchorError thrown in src/instructions/mint.rs:255. Error Code: NotFullyLoaded. Error Number: 6020. Error Message: Not all config lines were added to the candy machine.',
    'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR consumed 21205 of 972240 compute units',
    'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR failed: custom program error: 0x1784'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add all the items available, in this case 5 items. You should use `insertItems` for add the items.